# Use AddMaxEquality to find the max sum of bools

Tags: python, max, min, or-tools

How can one use AddMinEquality and AddMaxEquality to distribute assignments evenly? My model variables are boolean, hence I try to minimize difference between maximum and minimum of sum of bools.

```
assignments = []
for c in cars:
    a = model.NewIntVar(0, total_assignments, c)
    model.Add(a == sum(car_sch[(d, c)] for d in days))
    assignments.append(a)

assignment_min = model.AddMinEquality(assignments)  
assignment_max = model.AddMaxEquality(assignments)

model.Minimize(assignment_max - assignment_min)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing

```
assignments = []
for c in cars:
    a = model.NewIntVar(0, total_assignments, c)
    model.Add(a == sum(car_sch[(d, c)] for d in days))
    assignments.append(a)

min_value = model.NewIntVar(0, total_assignments, "min val") 
assignment_min = model.AddMinEquality(assignments) 
max_value = model.NewIntVar(0, total_assignments, "max val") 
assignment_max = model.AddMaxEquality(assignments)

model.Minimize(max_value - min_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
Model.AddMinEquality(target_var, [expressions])
```

See the [documentation](https://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#CpModel.AddMinEquality)

Comment: Why is it necessary to define a target variable? In other languages, we just run min or max function over a vector of values. Could it not be inherited from expressions?

Comment: Because I do not like API that creates object silently. And arguments are not variables, the API accepts one variable linear expressions (a * x + b) everywhere.